# Несовместимость файлов или?

Tags: php, кодировка

Здравствуйте!

Я рисую график через pChart. Данные для графика должны получиться как результаты sql-запросов к БД. Пользователи по абциссе, производительность по ординате. Только когда пытаюсь подключить файлы вместе

```
include "pChart/pChart.class";
include "pChart/pData.class";
include "connection.php"; // здесь подключение к базе
```

все рушится и выводится не изображение, а "кракозябры". Почему? Как это можно исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, Вы не указали `header('Content-Type: image/png');` или `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');`

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте есть ли у Вас поддержка библиотеки GD.